# An extensive sausage making site

Tags: sausages

I have been looking for a website that offers recipes for sausage making at home, at an encyclopaedic level if it exists.. thespicysausage.com has some popular ones, but is there anything out there that is more diverse? I mean Chinese, Thai, Indian, Italian, etc etc? It seems that typing 'sausage recipe' into the web engines only offers recipes to make with already made sausages! :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no all-in-one sausage making site that I know of. However, many recipes can be found just by searching "home made sausage." You can further specify by searching individual types of sausage.  For example I recently searched for, and made, "home made Argentinian chorizo".

Comment: The website must me made then! :D

Comment: @IlyaGrushevskiy let me know when you create it.

Answer (score 1):

The charcuterie Bible is probably your best bet. A great amount of food related wisdom, not just sausage-related.

Charcuterie: The craft of salting, smoking and curing by Michael Ruhlman and Brian Polcyn.

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago i stumbled upon the repository of recipes from Len Poli of Sonoma Mountain Sausages.

Although it doesn't have a recipe for every sausage ever conceived, it is quite an extensive collection that also includes recipes for cured meats (hams etc).

heres the link:
http://lpoli.50webs.com/